# c++ recursion error

Tags: c++, recursion, raytracing

I have the following recursive code and it doesn't behave as expected (see details below):

```
R3Intersection ComputeIntersectionNode(R3Ray *ray, R3Node *node)
{
  R3Intersection closest_inter;
  R3Intersection child_inter;
  R3Intersection shape_inter;

  double least_t = DBL_MAX;

  // check for intersection with shape
  if(node->shape != NULL)
  {
    shape_inter = ComputeIntersectionShape(ray, node->shape);
    if(shape_inter.hit == 1)
      closest_inter = shape_inter;
  }

  // go through all the children and for each child, compute
  // the closest intersection with ray
  for(int i = 0; i < node->children.size(); i++)
  {
    // compute intersection with children[i] and ray
    child_inter = ComputeIntersectionNode(ray, node->children[i]);

    // if there's an intersection with the child node and
    // it is the closest intersection, set closest intersection
    if(child_inter.hit == 1 && fabs(child_inter.t) < fabs(least_t))
      closest_inter = child_inter;
  }

  return closest_inter;
}
```

This `ComputeIntersectionNode(...)`, in addition to the recursive calls, is also being called for multiple rays in the program. To test this function, I run it for 4 `rays` and 4 `nodes` (or more precisely, one `root` of type `node`, which doesn't have a `shape`, but has 4 `children`, each of which have one `shape`). For testing, each `ray` intersects exactly one `node`/`shape`.

When I run the code in GDB for the first `ray`, it first passes the `root` through the code, which doesn't have a `shape`, so then it goes directly to the `children`. It computes the first child's intersection correctly and sets the `closest_inter` variable correctly as well, which gets returned to the highest level of recursion and `child_inter` as well as `closest_inter` are set here with `child_inter.hit = 1;`

Then, the second child is processed. `ComputeIntersectionShape(...)` returns no intersection with the second child (`shape_inter.hit == 0`;) - this is expected behavior. However, when the function returns to the highest level of recursion, for some reason child_inter.hit is set to 1 (but should be set to 0).

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you missing a `break` in the `for` loop?

Comment: Does the R3Intersection default constructor explicitly initialize hit?

Comment: @atlpeg: I don't wish to break once I find the intersection because I wish to find the CLOSEST intersection so I must loop over all children

Comment: @markB: this was actually the cause of the problem. I didn't have a default constructor so it didn't initialize hit. When I initialized hit explicitly in the beginning of the function, this problem no longer persisted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by the fact you are returning a default-initialized `R3Intersection` (ie. you don't return the `shape_inter` when it doesn't intersect). Depending on its default constructor, you might get what you see.